# Quick blox - Signature generation issue

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am trying to use this [link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#CombinedAPIUserAuthentication) to get described response:

```
{
  "session": {
    "application_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-04-03T07:34:48Z",
    "device_id": null,
    "id": 743,
    "nonce": 1308205278,
    "token": "0e7bc95d85c0eb2bf052be3d29d3df523081e87f",
    "ts": 1333438438,
    "updated_at": "2012-04-03T07:34:48Z",
    "user_id": null
  }
}
```

But now it say application not found:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error>No application found</error>
</errors>
```

Can't go ahead to test another requests. This is a shell script I used for getting curl request:

```
timestamp=`date +%s`

body="application_id=HIDDENAPPLICATIONIDHERE&auth_key=HIDDENAUTHKEYHERE&nonce=2342546&timestamp=$timestamp"

signature=`echo -n $body | openssl sha -hmac HIDDENSECRETHERE`

body=$body"&signature="$signature

#echo $body
#echo $signature

#exit 0

curl -X POST \
-H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" \
-d $body \
https://api.quickblox.com/session.xml
```

So there some info regrding this maybe I've created shell script to a wrong way:

> HMAC-SHA function of the body of the request, with a key auth_secret.
>   Request body is formed as the sorted (sorting alphabetically, as
>   symbols, not as bytes) by increase the string array 'parameter=value',
>   separated with the symbol "&". For the parameters passed as a
>   user[id]=123 is used just such a line of user[id]=123

Also I've prepped a [Swift project](https://github.com/matrosovDev/QuickBloxApiTest/tree/master/QuickBloxTest) how to generate signature and get session, but still has the same error with no application found.

Any recommendation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please verify Application ID parameter because server return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error>No application found</error>
</errors>
```

For example generate signature (Java):

```
    Random random = new Random();

    String nonce = Integer.toString(random.nextInt());
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String timestamp = Long.toString(time);
    String signature;

    String str = "application_id=" + applicationId + "&" + "auth_key=" + authKey + "&" + "nonce="
            + nonce + "&" + "timestamp=" + timestamp + "&" + "user[login]=" + adminLogin + "&" + "user[password]="
            + adminPassword;

    signature = UtilsMethods.calculateHMAC_SHA(str, authSecret);
```

calculateHMAC_SHA:

```
private static final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";

    public static String calculateHMAC_SHA(String data, String key) throws SignatureException {
        String result = null;
        try {

            // get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

            // get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
            mac.init(signingKey);

            byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(digest.length * 2);
            String s;
            for (byte b : digest) {
                s = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & b);
                if (s.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append('0');
                }

                sb.append(s);
            }

            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: thanks Andrey I will check and let you know, really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Hey Andrey, I've tried to use your recommendation and I built Swift project https://github.com/matrosovDev/QuickBloxApiTest/tree/master/QuickBloxTest where I tried to do the same but still get "No application found", I've rechecked app id and I am totally sure that is correct as I copied it using button on the web site. In my example I leave empty fields in Consts.swift as I don't want to share mine. But you can use any of your app to check it. Thanks for help again!

Comment: Please use  let dictionary = ["application_id": Consts.applicationId, "auth_key": Consts.authKey, "timestamp": timestamp, "nonce": nonce, "signature": signature, "user[login]" :Consts.userLogin, "user[password]": Consts.password] in QBRequest and let timestamp = String(Int(time)) in main.swift (this worked for me)

Comment: thanks for comments, just replaced it, but still the same issue `Optional("{\"errors\":{\"base\":[\"No application found\"]}}")` I use the user login and password that is connected to my http://adminirislive.quickblox.com/apps/30853/ am I right?

Comment: I've updated my code with your recommendation, can you please check it. Maybe I need to use other login and password as well.

Comment: do you know what can be a problem?